# Prestashop External Payment Module

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have created an external payment module to my prestashop (1.7) store. The payment is process via external server with redirecion.
After payment success, how can I redirect to my shop page to confirm the order?
What is the exact URL, that I should redirect from external payment site to my shop page?

NOTE : The external site is passing values via POST mechanism

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to understand this mechanism is to do a little review of different payment modules, best way for such a redirection is to have dedicated `ModuleFrontController` with all the necessary validation in this file.

You can start from this:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/paymentexample

Comment: I have tried to post the values using this github file. But there also I could not find  a solution of return URL from external payment processor to my shop page for updating order status with posted values

Comment: i think that you need to check documentation of this payment provider, most of the time you need to sent some extra param like "back_url" and this payment provider will send a data to this page